# Train, Test, Validate split Python. Three sets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

Someone presented a solution to split a dataset into three sets. I wonder where is the label in this case. Or how to set the labels then.

```
train, validate, test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), [int(.6*len(df)), int(.8*len(df))])
```

Comment: What do you mean with labels? You get returned 3 objects, which are `train`, `validate` and `test`, the first one covers 60% of the `df`, the second (`validate`) from 60% to 80% and the last one (`test`) the last 20% remaining. The labels are part of your dataset, they needn't be distinguished while splitting.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky By labels I mean, y_train and y_test in this code.
    { X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.2) }

Comment: @Curious Aren't those just variable names? Please clarify your question, and be careful.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile. I believe the question is quite clear.  Answers are given below. I don't understand what should I be careful of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer the question based on comments:

Using this method for splitting:

```
train, validate, test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), [int(.6*len(df)), int(.8*len(df))])
```

You are getting 3 different objects, which consist of the first 60% of data from `df` for `train`, the data corresponding to the interval between 60% and 80% for `validate` and the last 20% corresponding to 80%-100% in `test`. The labels are within these dataframes.

In `train_test_split` you are passing two objects, X and Y, which have been most likely previously split from an original dataset and getting in return 4 objects, 2 corresponding to train and two corresponding to test. Keep in mind this: You are first splitting your dataset into `independent variables` and `explained/target variable`, and then splitting these two objects into train and test.

With `np.split` you are going the otherway around, you are first splitting your dataset into 3 objects, train, validate and test which will later need to be split individually into `independent variables` commonly known as X and `target variable` known as Y. You are doing the same splits, just in reverse order.

However, keep in mind that by passing the indexes for `np.split` it means the splitting is not performed randomly, whereas with `train_test_split` you get a random train and test subesets. `np.split` on the other hand, allows for more flexibility, for instance, as you prove with your example, creating more than 2 subsets.

Maybe this will help!
[image]

Comment: Appreciated for the explanatory answer. Very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Feed the output of one of the train_test_split into a second one as input

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4)
X_test, X_validate, y_test, y_validate = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5)
```

The function randomly splits 2 arrays into 4 arrays, and test_size determines the size of the split allocated to the test output vs train. The y input is meant to be a target for building a machine learning model and X is meant to be the features for the model. If you want them combined, then just concat the equivalent X and y outputs.

Comment: In my case, this one will work perfectly. Can we add the random seed number in this method?

Comment: Yes, you can use a random seed with this

Comment: MBA Coder That will be separate seed to each line right?

Comment: Curious, you would need to do a seed for each line